# Wie nennt man die Eigenschaft, wenn eine Person die Dinge nimmt, wie sie kommen?

Tags: single-word-request

Zu beschreiben wäre eine Person, die mit Dingen gut spontan umgehen kann, die sich aber auch nicht große Sorgen darum macht. Es ist auch inbegriffen, dass sie mit positiven wie negativen Dingen umgeht, ohne groß etwas daran ändern zu wollen oder es zu versuchen. Das Wort sollte neutral oder positiv konnotiert sein.

Ich dachte erst an "Beständigkeit" oder "Lässigkeit", aber finde nicht, dass diese Wörter wirklich zutreffen. "Sie nimmt es, wie es kommt".

Welche Eigenschaft ist hier zuzuordnen?

Comment: Wie wäre es mit Gelassenheit?

Comment: Probier's mal mit Gemütlichkeit, mit Ruhe und Gemütlichkeit jagst Du den Alltag und die Sorgen weg.

Comment: Eine Person, die die Dinge nimmt, wie sie kommen, nicht aus der Ruhe zu bringen ist, ist m.E. das Gegenteil von einer spontanen Person. Eine spontane Person reagiert m.E. impulsiv und ist im Gegenteil leicht zu erregen, ob ins Euphorische oder Deprimierte.

Comment: @userunknown Da steht nicht, dass die Person "spontan" sei, sondern mit Dingen "spontan umgehen" kann. Das ist was Anderes und schon gar nicht implulsiv.

Comment: @tofro: "spontan: 1) aus einem plötzlichen Impuls heraus, auf einem plötzlichen Entschluss beruhend, einem plötzlichen inneren Antrieb, Impuls folgend" (Google-Treffer 1, spontan, Quelle: "Wörterbuch").

Comment: @userunknown Soso. Und was steht bei "spontan reagieren" / "mit etwas spontan umgehen"?

Comment: @tofro: Das ergibt sich ja aus der Bedeutung des Wortes "spontan". Aber ich bin sicher mit etwas Überlegung kommt auch soso-tofro alleine drauf.

Comment: @tofro: 'mit spontan auftretenden Ereignissen gut umgehen können' ist wohl, was du meinst und nicht 'mit Ereignissen spontan gut umgehen können' (das schreibst du aber). Ersteres kann man verschieden tun (spontan, gelassen, gleichmütig...), letzteres impliziert die Verhaltensweise schon : nämlich spontan - und folglich nicht unbedingt gelassen

Comment: Der Kölner sagt dazu "et kütt wie et kütt".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gelassenheit ist hier der passende Ausdruck.
Dinge sein lassen, annehmen, nicht alles ändern oder beeinflussen wollen: Das Leben gelassen angehen.

Comment: Stimmt, danke, danach hatte Ich gesucht. Auch Synonyme dazu die Ich im Internet gefunden habe, haben zur Beschreibung gepasst.

Comment: Und das würdest Du auch "spontan" nennen?

Answer (score 10):

Mir fällt da spontan Gleichmut ein, man könnte auch von stoischer Ruhe sprechen. Im ausgeprägterem Fall wäre das Fatalismus.

Comment: Danke für den Input! Die Idee hatte ich auch, war mir dann eben etwas zu stoisch (also man kann sich zusätzlich für etwas begeistern). Passt aber auf jeden Fall auf die Beschreibung!

Comment: Und das würdest Du auch "spontan" nennen?

Answer (score 7):

Ein möglicher passender Begriff ist der *Stoiker*, dessen hauptsächliche Eigenschaft ist, eben die Dinge so zu nehmen, wie sie kommen - und mit ihnen fertig zu werden, ein Schicksal anzunehmen und in würdevoller Art möglichst positiv auszufüllen.

Dieser Begriff wird allerdings bisweilen auch (an sich falsch und negativ konnotiert) verwendet, um emotions- oder auch antriebslose Charaktere - bis hin zum Fatalismus - zu beschreiben. In seinem ursprünglichen Sinn passt er allerdings wie die Faust aufs Auge.

*Stoisch* ist das passende Adjektiv dazu, *Stoismus* der "Zustand", der sich daraus ergibt.

Comment: Danke! Wie bezeichnet man dann die Eigenschaft als solche? Ich konnte im Internet nichts zu "Stoik" finden, und "Stoa" bezeichnet eher die Schule. Interessanter Input, da das Wort veraltet ist. Es wird mir sicher nutzen!

Comment: letzter Absatz.

Comment: Und das würdest Du auch "spontan" nennen?

Answer (score 3):

Wie Olafant würde ich eine solche Person

> gelassen

nennen oder auch

> ausgeglichen

Comment: Und das würdest Du auch "spontan" nennen?

Comment: @userunknown: Dieses »spontan« bezieht sich darauf, dass sich die Person schon in der Anfangsphase besonderer Entwicklungen nicht aus dem Gleichgewicht bringen lässt, was ich mit Gelassenheit und Ausgeglichenheit durchaus in Verbindung bringen würde.

Comment: Du meinst eine Person, die spontan unspontan sein kann und es auch eigentlich dauernd ist, also nicht spontan?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich glaube, dass der OP mit seinem »gut spontan umgehen« »sofort, von Anfang an, unmittelbar gut umgehen« meint.

Comment: Du meinst er meint mit "gut spontan" "spontan gut"? Wäre das nicht ein Anlass erst nachzufragen? Wenn man das Wort "spontan" aus der Frage streicht, dann wirkt sie sehr viel konsistenter. Ich würde dann zu stoisch neigen, wobei "gelassen" und "ausgeglichen" eher der Anforderung entsprechen, tendenziell positiv bewertet zu werden. Aber ohne Bestätigung, dass das "spontan" da fehl am Platz ist, möchte ich Deine Antwort nicht hochpuschen.

Comment: @userunknown Ich stimme Dir zu. Du solltest eine eigene Antwort schreiben.